# How to create a new list by comparing elements' string of two list for the case shown below?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists -

```
List1 = [abcde,fghij,klmno,pqrst,uvwxy]
List2 = [cde,ghij,no,pqr]
```

Output I want: `List3 = [pqrst,uvwxy]`

As you can see the elements of the List2 are sub-string of some of the elements of List1. But the sub-string should match the characters starting from the right hand side. For example, although 'pqr' of List2 is a sub-string of the element 'pqrst' of List1 but pqrst has a trailing character 't', so I wanted to put it into another list. I wanted to compare both the List and get a new List, say List3 that contains = [pqrst,uvwxy].

What is the best way to do it using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `endswith` and simple loops in this case.

```
list1 = ['abcde','fghij','klmno','pqrst','uvwxy']
list2 = ['cde','ghij','no','pqr']
list3 = []
for i in list1:
    bool1 = 0
    for j in list2:
        if i.endswith(j): bool1 = 1
    if not bool1: list3.append(i)

print(list3)    # output:  ['pqrst', 'uvwxy']
```